# GCE Ram performance restriction

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gce-persistent-disk

I'm wondering how GCE instances ram's IOPS and throughput was restricted?
I can see disk IOPS and throughput limit by [1], but there seems no doc telling that instance ram's limit.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/performance

Comment: RAM performance is not restricted in the same manner as disk IOPS. However, RAM performance is a factor, to some degree, of the number of VMs sharing the host memory.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks for replying! So, Is there any way to determine how much memory I need to handle the traffic? I can adjust the disk class or size based on monitoring metrics that shows the peak of disk IOPS / throughput, but how do the memory?

Comment: You will need to benchmark your system and applications to know.